# How to create a surface plot on a multiple line 3d plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, contour

Using `plot3` I have created a multiple discrete line 3d plot. How can I fill the 3d surface these lines create (basically join the lines with a surface)?

Answer (score 1):

Using `fill3` can help.

```
x = [0 0 5 5 0];
y = [5 5 0 0 5];
z = [0 5 5 0 0];
subplot(1,2,1)
plot3(x,y,z,'LineWidth',5);
grid on
subplot(1,2,2)
fill3(x,y,z,'y')
grid on
```

[image]